# Getting Top Hook in C via dylib on Mac OS

Tags: c++, c, macos, dylib

So my goal is to compile my code and another subhook file to result in a dylib through the use of the command, however for some reason the command and code that worked a few months ago no longer works now.

The purpose of this code would be to hook and unhook

`g++ -dynamiclib -fPIC -o out.dylib main.cpp subhook.c -std=c++11`

The code in debate:

```
DWORD luaState = 0;

uint64_t GetModuleHandle(void)
{
    char path[1024];
    uint32_t size = sizeof(path);
    if (_NSGetExecutablePath(path, &size) != 0) return -1;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < _dyld_image_count(); i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(_dyld_get_image_name(i), path) == 0) {
            const struct segment_command_64* cmd = getsegbyname("__TEXT");
            uint64_t addr = cmd->vmaddr;
            return addr + _dyld_get_image_vmaddr_slide(i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

#define x(x) (x + (DWORD)GetModuleHandle())

typedef int (*getttok)(DWORD);
getttok r_gettop = (getttok)x(0x100402e60);

subhook_t gettophook;
int gettop_hook(DWORD x) {
    subhook_remove(gettophook);
    subhook_free(gettophook);
    luaState = x;
     return x;
}

__attribute__((constructor)) void DllMain() 
{ 
    gettophook = subhook_new((void*)r_gettop, (void *)gettop_hook, (subhook_flags_t)0);
    subhook_install(gettophook);

    while (luaState == 0) {
        //request("waiting_for_result", "true");
        sleep(1);
    }

    //request("luastate", tostring(luaState));
    //continue 

}
```

I seem to be getting 18 errors in total, and I hope that I am missing something obvious that is the solution to my code, but would me being on my mac be a reason for this?
Below are only some of the errors as stack wont let me list too much code.

```
clang: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
main.cpp:1:1: error: unknown type name 'DWORD'
DWORD luaState = 0;
^
main.cpp:3:1: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
uint64_t GetModuleHandle(void)
^
main.cpp:6:5: error: unknown type name 'uint32_t'
    uint32_t size = sizeof(path);
    ^
main.cpp:8:10: error: unknown type name 'uint32_t'
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < _dyld_image_count(); i++)
         ^
main.cpp:8:30: error: use of undeclared identifier '_dyld_image_count'
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < _dyld_image_count(); i++)
```

```
                         ^
```

Comment: "clang: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated" - This bit should be easy enough to fix. Just build your code as C++ (and, possibly, rename your source files).

Comment: Hi @JesperJuhl , the file is named main.cpp, shouldn't this be enough to get rid of that warning? I believe I'll just need to go through my code to make sufficient changes to get it to compile, thanks for the help tho.

Comment: The file name is mostly irrelevant.

Comment: @JesperJuhl The warning has disappeared, now my goal is to get rid of all the other errors, I believe it's likely that the errors are due to me not using #include for directories required to use this code.